# Online course for geometric algebra, reference request

Tags: reference-request

I want to study [geometric algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) in my spare time, and I have found many resources about it already. These resources range from books, to notes and articles. However its very difficult to find an actual course on this subject (including lectures and exercises).

[Opencourseware](http://search.mit.edu/search?site=ocw&client=mit&getfields=%2a&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=http://ocw.mit.edu/search/google-ocw.xsl&proxyreload=1&as_dt=i&oe=utf-8&departmentName=web&filter=0&courseName=&q=geometric%20algebra&btnG.x=18&btnG.y=16) has some material online on this subject, but most are not exactly what Im looking for and all of them are incomplete. Other sites such as coursera and edx only have entry level math courses.

I could not find any useful questions on math.stackexchange. Several topics on mathoverflow give references for this subject, but I think some extra materials would help me master the subject. If anybody has any good sources for such content it would help me very much. Thanks!

Comment: Your title and first paragraph name "geometric algebra" as the subject you are interested in, but later paragraphs give links to courses on linear algebra and resources on geometric topology and abstract algebra and you tagged the question with algebraic geometry. It's really not clear what subject you are looking for information on, and in any case, I think you're better off asking this on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: When you use the expression *geometric algebra*, you might mean the approach to classical mechanics and linear algebra due to David Hestenes, using Clifford algebras. Hestenes's approach is not covered in any of the sources you have listed, but it is the interpretation that Shuchang Zhang took of your question. Maybe you could clarify what you mean by ``geometric algebra''. Do you mean something like Emil Artin meant: algebra with an emphasis on geometric intuition and group actions?

Comment: @BenMcKay I did mean the [Clifford algebra of a vector space over the field of real numbers endowed with a quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra). I will correct my question for that.

Comment: @j.c. I have removed the wrong tag. The link to OCW`s list of linear algebra courses was the only list there that I could find with geometric algebra in it. There were no geometric algebra courses on coursera and edx, what I tried to show in those links. The links to other mathoverflow questions were the closest matches I could find, I put them there to not get flamed for not trying to find an answer myself :). I will adapt my question to make it more clear then. Ive been looking around at the math SE as well, but I could find more information on the topic here than there.

Comment: @j.c. Ah Ive read ["What kind of questions can I ask here?"](http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic) now. Indeed this is not a question about research, sorry about that. Should I remove it? I did not think I would get useful references at mathematics.stackexchange, the answer I got here was helpful although not exactly what I asked.

Comment: The link to `search.mit.edu` is broken (it now redirects to `web.mit.edu`). I presume it is meant to point to a [search](https://ocw.mit.edu/search/?q=geometric+algebra) for "geometric algebra" at [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can start with very elementary and introductory notes like [Geometric Algebra](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5935v1) by Eric Chrsolm and also [An Introduction to Geometric Algebra and Calculus](http://montgomerycollege.edu/Departments/planet/planet/Numerical_Relativity/bookGA.pdf) by Alan Bromborsky. [A Survey of Geometric Algebra and Geometric Calculus](http://faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/GA&GC.pdf) by Alan Macdonald gives several references you can take.

After known basics of geometric algebra, you could read some systematic textbooks. For example [Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/CA_to_GC.html) and [New Foundations for Classical Mechanics](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/NFCM.html) by David Hestenes are classical textbooks on this topic. [Geometric Algebra for Physicsts](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~cjld1/pages/book.htm) is also a pretty good book.